# mssql: monitoring/trace permissions used

Tags: sql-server, permissions, monitoring, privileges, minimize

for GDPR reasons i like to give "tailor-made" permissions to our Developers and to other logins that have at the moment db_owner-rights.

Our security-team asked me, if it is possible to monitor, which permissions this logins uses in fact.

The idea is to monitor for a month which privileges the logins uses and after have collected this information go to discuss with the developers.

If the developers pretends to have db_owner - permissions (or even higher permissions), than i can argument: 
"Look, in the last month in reality you used only this, this, and this permission and so i don't think you need really db_owner - rights..."

I have done some research but i don't find a solution that sadisfys this goal:

- The default trace don't traces all used permissions.
- Maybe with extended events i can achieve my goal
- SQL Auditing seems to be an other possibility
- Triggers seems a bad way to achieve my goal

So i ask, someone has done this kind of "monitoring" too and can tell me how it has implemented it?

I need it for SQL 2014 and newer versions...

Thanks

Comment: If you're trying to limit permissions, then the best method (I've found) is to go in with low permissions at the start. Give the users the minimal permissions you think they need to get their job done; that might simply be Execute on SP's in a specific schema. Then, as needs require, add additional permissions when users have problems or find out they are trying to do things they shouldn't. Users will "aim high" with the permissions they need, and the DBAs need to therefore aim low; as it's easy to tell when a user tries to do something they can't. Just be prepared for the phone calls.

Comment: Hi Larnu, thanks for your consideration. The problem is, that i have a lot of old logins to "sanify", so they have db_owner - rights in production and i cannot risk to reduce rights without knowing what permissions they use in fact...

Comment: Sounds like you need to implement roles too, if all the permissions are set at user level. If you can't risk reducing their rights, and you don't know what rights they need, and you *think* they are telling you they need more rights than they need (which they probably are, even if only to a small degree) then you're in a limbo here. I think you need to take a step back and discuss internally what your users are supposed to be able to do, and then go from there. The problem appears to be internal, not database related.

Comment: Its not only internal. A lot of applications that we buyed have in their requirements "db_owner" - rights. And i am certain, that some of them needs lesser rights than db_owner. But not in all caseses we have support contracts to ask the external companys abaout the least privleges. So with a tracing what permissions they use in fact, gives me the possibility to reduce the permissions without impacting the service in production...

Comment: If it the applications, then test in your development environment and see what breaks; that's what it's there for. it's how i worked out the minimal permissions for our main software (which is vendor supplied).